# Swift 4 download Swedens radio channels

Tags: json, swift, struct

I got the same error when I try to get previous  and song that play right now for every channel. I think something is wrong in my struct Root and playlist because data is not in the correct format.I am using Swift 4 and  trying to learn JSON, but its hard. Previous struct is same as Song struct.
 How do I fix my error?

My code looks now:

```
*struct Root : Decodable {
    let copyright : String
    let channels : [Channel]
    let pagination : Pagination
    //let playlists : [Playlist]
}

struct Channel : Decodable {
    let image : String
    let imagetemplate : String
    let color : String
    let tagline : String?
    let siteurl : String
    let id : Int
    let url : URL?
    let statkey : String?
    let scheduleurl : String
    let channeltype : String
    let name : String
}

struct Pagination : Decodable {
    let page, size, totalhits, totalpages : Int
    let nextpage : URL
}

struct  Playlist : Decodable{
    let id : Int
    let name :String
    let prev : [previoussong]
    let song : [Song]
}

struct Song : Decodable  {
    let  title : String
    let description : String
    let artist : String
    let composer :String
    let conductor : String
    let albumname : String
    let recordlabel : String
    let lyricist : String
    let producer : String
    let starttimeutc : String
    let stopttimeutc : String

}
var tests = [Channel]()
var pl = [Playlist]()

    func downloadStations(){
        let test2 = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/channels?format=json"
        let play = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow?format=json"

        let url = URL(string: test2) /// play instead of test2
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data , response, error) in
           do{
            let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
            self.tests = root.channels
            //self.pl = root.playlists
            for eachStations in self.tests {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.tableV.reloadData()
                }
          }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}.resume()*
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't return the array of channels. It returns an object:

```
{
    "copyright": "somestring",
    "pagination": {},
    "channels": []
}
```

So, `copyright` is not a part of `channel` and you have an object with field `channels`.

Answer (score 0):

Please read the JSON carefully. In the root object there is the key `copyright` and a key `channels` which contains the channel array.

You need to add an umbrella struct for the root object.

Please name the channel struct in singular form and with starting uppercase letter (`Channel`). Further some keys in the struct are optional.

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let copyright : String
    let channels : [Channel]
    let pagination : Pagination
}

struct Channel : Decodable {
    let image : String
    let imagetemplate : String
    let color : String
    let tagline : String?
    let siteurl : String
    let id : Int
    let url : URL?
    let statkey : String?
    let scheduleurl : String
    let channeltype : String
    let name : String
}

struct Pagination : Decodable {
    let page, size, totalhits, totalpages : Int
    let nextpage : URL
}
```

---

```
var tests = [Channel]()
```

---

```
let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
self.tests = root.channels
```

Comment: Thanks it works now. I am new to Json, but I try to learn it now.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I try to get previous and song that play right now for every channel. How do I fix this?

**My code looks now:**

```
struct Root : Decodable {
    let copyright : String
    let channels : [Channel]
    let pagination : Pagination
    //let playlists : [Playlist]
}

struct Channel : Decodable {
    let image : String
    let imagetemplate : String
    let color : String
    let tagline : String?
    let siteurl : String
    let id : Int
    let url : URL?
    let statkey : String?
    let scheduleurl : String
    let channeltype : String
    let name : String
}

struct Pagination : Decodable {
    let page, size, totalhits, totalpages : Int
    let nextpage : URL
}

struct  Playlist : Decodable{
    let id : Int
    let name :String
    let prev : [previoussong]
    let song : [Song]
}
struct previoussong : Decodable  {
    let  title : String
    let description : String
    let artist : String
    let composer :String
    let conductor : String
    let albumname : String
    let recordlabel : String
    let lyricist : String
    let producer : String
    let starttimeutc : String
    let stopttimeutc : String

}
struct Song : Decodable  {
    let  title : String
    let description : String
    let artist : String
    let composer :String
    let conductor : String
    let albumname : String
    let recordlabel : String
    let lyricist : String
    let producer : String
    let starttimeutc : String
    let stopttimeutc : String

}
var tests = [Channel]()
var pl = [Playlist]()
    var stationsName:String?

    @IBOutlet weak var tableV: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var image: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var songLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableV.dataSource = self

        downloadStations()
    }
    func downloadStations(){
        let test2 = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/channels?format=json"
        let play = "http://api.sr.se/api/v2/playlists/rightnow?format=json"

        let url = URL(string: test2) /// play instead of test2
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){ (data , response, error) in
           do{
            let root = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data!)
            self.tests = root.channels
            //self.pl = root.playlists
            for eachStations in self.tests {
                self.stationsName = eachStations.name
                print(" " + self.stationsName!)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    self.tableV.reloadData()
                }
          }
    } catch {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }
}.resume()
```